# With nouveau driver, resume from hibernate or suspend results in wrong color display

Tags: linux, display, nvidia-graphics-card

I am using the nouveau driver on my Ubuntu 10.10. Everything looks right until one day I resume from hibernate. The color of the display is weird. It is somehow too bright. (Sorry I don't have a camera.) Same when I start another X or use `fbi` to display images under console. I have to restart my computer to get it right. Any hint to fix this?

The driver was installed from the official software source. And when I use the official nvidia driver, there's no such problem.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced what you described with a NVIDIA® GeForce 7050 / nForce 630A MCP under linux 4.4.14. Using the nvidia driver was no option, because although this issue didn't occur with the blob, among other things multiple different graphics deformations appeared and I even couldn't watch videos with it.

The solution in my case was to uninstall the nvidia blob again and to **not modeset during boot before the nouveau driver had taken over control.** In my case I just reconfigured lilo by commenting out the "vga=" line in lilo.conf and then ran the lilo command to install the reconfigured boot loader. The system including the graphics and resuming from hibernation or standby works great with the nouveau driver now.